# Apply formula to a numeric part of cell value

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Spreadsheet, I have a column of task IDs, with values like `T1`, `T2`, `T13` (i.e. all values starting with the same text). I would like to use a formula on the values of these cells (for conditional formatting). Can I somehow apply it only to the numeric part of the value, i.e. 1, 2, 13? Something like `=max((A1:A100)[2:end])`?